# Index Out Of Range Error in Xcode

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, tableview

I am creating an app that uses a database, and am using labels to display the information.  I first created a label that has date information, and when I ran the app it worked properly. When I added a second label for the away team information, I ran it and got an error that said : "Thread 1 Fatal Error : Index Out Of Range."  Would this be related to the database, or the table view itself?

[image]
Here is the code :

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class srFootballViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var ref = DatabaseReference()
    var Date = [String]()
    var awayTeam = [String]()
    var databaseHandle:DatabaseHandle = 0
    var databaseHandle2:DatabaseHandle = 0

    @IBOutlet var footballTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ref = Database.database().reference()
        databaseHandle = ref.child("Dates").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in

            let post = snapshot.value as? String
            if let actualPost = post {
                self.Date.append(actualPost)
                self.footballTableView.reloadData()
            }
        }

        databaseHandle2 = ref.child("awayTeams").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in

            let post2 = snapshot.value as? String
            if let actualPost2 = post2 {
                self.awayTeam.append(actualPost2)
                self.footballTableView.reloadData()
            }
        }

    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return Date.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let footballCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "footballCell") as! srFootballCell
        footballCell.date.text = Date[indexPath.row]
        footballCell.awayTeam.text = awayTeam[indexPath.row]

        return(footballCell)
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }




}
```

Comment: There are currently three different answers - which are all (mostly) correct. There are a couple of inherent issues in the Firebase structure as there is no direct correlation between dates and away teams. It's a little unclear what you are actually trying to do but it may be a good idea to store dates in a *play_dates* node and keep a reference to which team is playing on that date within that same node. Then you can load all of that into an array of classes for your tableView. /play_dates/childByAutoId/date: 20180420 and /team: team_id within that same node.

Answer (score 1):

First you don't name a variable starting with capital letter.
Second since you're using two different arrays for loading data in table view, awayTeam is crashing your app, because it doesn't have as many elements as Date array, because you're using Date.count for number of rows in section.

Change

```
databaseHandle = ref.child("Dates").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in

        let post = snapshot.value as? String
        if let actualPost = post {
            self.Date.append(actualPost)
            self.footballTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

to

```
databaseHandle = ref.child("Dates").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in

    let post = snapshot.value as? String
    if let actualPost = post {
        self.Date.append(actualPost)
    }
}
```

So you won't reload table view data before loading awayTeam data.

Answer (score 1):

Your `awayTeam` and `Date` arrays have different count of items - be sure to have same amount in order to prevent this crash - even better, create an object that will contain both of them.

Also, do NOT name your variable `Date` as it would conflict with Date class.

Answer (score 1):

First of all do not use `Date` as a variable name. `Date` is a reserved word for a Swift struct. Swift variable names are supposed to start with a lowercase letter anyway.

The error occurs because the `observe` methods work asynchronously and you are using two different arrays at data source.

At the moment you are calling `reloadData` in the first `observe` completion block `awayTeam` is still empty and accessing item 0 causes the crash.

The solution is to call `reloadData()` only in the second ovserver or – more reliable – use `DispatchGroup` to notify when all database operations are completed. Apart from that it's highly recommended to use a custom struct as data source rather than multiple arrays.